# How to enable Web Bluetooth on Samsung Internet browser?

Tags: web-bluetooth

Samsung has recently announced [Internet beta](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sec.android.app.sbrowser.beta&hl=en) v6.2 with [Web Bluetooth](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2015/07/interact-with-ble-devices-on-the-web). How is this enabled?

Answer (score 2):

1. Navigate to `internet://flags/#enable-web-bluetooth`
2. Enable it, restart.
3. Try a simple sample, such as [Device Info](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/web-bluetooth/device-info.html?allDevices=true).

Comment: Thanks Vincent! Just to add that since v6.4 it is now enabled by default (no flag switching required): https://medium.com/samsung-internet-dev/lets-connect-with-samsung-internet-v6-4-stable-1f197d43a812